# making a JSON file from user's input

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to use `JSON` as some kind of database for my application. So the user adds an input and it's written to the JSON file, then when I need that information I can loop through the JSON. 
I'm using `'fs'` to write the JSON format of my object inside file:

```
fs.appendFile('log.json',  JSON.stringify(customer) + '\n' , function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('saved in log.json');
});
```

So my `log.json` looks like this:

```
{"name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com"}
{"name":"Peter","email":"Peter@gmail.com"}
```

This is still can be used if I read each line and convert it to object, but obviously it's not a valid `JSON` file and it'd be better if I can have this as output:

```
{
{"name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com"},
{"name":"Peter","email":"Peter@gmail.com"}
}
```

or even better:

```
[
{"name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com"},
{"name":"Peter","email":"Peter@gmail.com"}
]
```

So technically all I want to do is keeping `{}` and append my text inside curly braces. Please note that I can't store all of the inputs in an array/object and then write that in my log file. I want an external-module-free method to update my `log.json` file every time user enters new information.

Comment: Maybe you would want to look at mongodb and how node.js does it?

Comment: Have you considered SQLite? It works with the same premise of keeping a simple text file as a database, and will be much faster when running as well as faster to implement.

Comment: Can you explain that last paragraph a bit more? The approach I would take is to read in the input file each time, parse it as JSON, push an entry to the returned array and then write the entire file back as JSON. Obviously, if the file will get large, this won't hold up as a good solution.

Comment: well using a db is not an option here. I'm trying to write an app to use json as a db for Azure, since apparently Microsoft doesn't want to add one for student accounts.

Comment: @GregL Yes that would be an option if the server runs constantly. All of the data would be gone if it restarts for any reason.

Comment: Use another data service...no shortage of them around. Wit til you need to do any indexing or searching will have to pull into array. roll your own db isn't very scalable

Comment: If a valid json in the file is not a concern, how about reading the content from file if it exists, wrapping with '[' and ']', parse and cache as array object in memory on first time load. For read, use the array object and for write, insert a new record in array and file both (for backup). While appending the record in file, if the array is not empty then prefix ","

Comment: I came up with using regex to replace the closing bracket and add the string to the file: `var result = data.replace(/\]$/g, new_param);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, using regex to replace closing bracket for each new entry:

```
if (data.length < 5) {
    console.log(data.length);
    new_json = JSON.stringify(customer) + '\n' + ']';
    result = data.replace(/\]$/g, new_json);
} else {
    new_json = ',' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '\n' + ']';
    result = data.replace(/\]$/g, new_json);
}
```

then you can parse the file using `JSON.parse`

```
fs.writeFile('log.json', result, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
        fs.readFile('log.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend a database. If you really want to do it this way though, you could open the file, seek backwards from the end until you find `]`, write your new data, and write `]` again.

Comment: You haven't taken into account the commas.